# How to resolve "C2660 'SWidget::Construct': function does not take 1 arguments"?

Tags: c++, widget, unreal-engine4

How can I resolve

> C2660 'SWidget::Construct': function does not take 1 arguments

I am trying to put a widget that displays the controls of the game.
I am new to Unreal Engine.

Error

> C2660 **'SWidget::Construct': function does not take 1 arguments**
> C:\Program Files\Epic Games\**UE_4.26**\Engine\Source\Runtime\SlateCore\Public\Widgets\*DeclarativeSyntaxSupport.h* 862

SPanelWidget.h

```
#pragma once

#include "SlateBasics.h"
#include "SlateExtras.h"

class SPanelWidget : public SCompoundWidget
{
public:

    SLATE_BEGIN_ARGS(SPanelWidget) {}
    SLATE_ARGUMENT(TWeakObjectPtr<class AControlPanel>, OwningPanel)
    SLATE_END_ARGS()

    void construct(const FArguments& InArgs);

    TWeakObjectPtr<class AControlPanel> OwningPanel;

    virtual bool SupportsKeyboardFocus() const override {return true;};

};
```

SPanelWidget.cpp

```
#include "SPanelWidget.h"

#define LOCTEXT_NAMESPACE "Panel"

void SPanelWidget::construct(const FArguments& InArgs) {
    const FText TitleText = LOCTEXT("ProjectTitle","Chair Table Practice Problem");
    const FMargin ContentPadding = FMargin(500.f,300.f);
    ChildSlot [
        SNew(SOverlay)
            + SOverlay::Slot()
            .HAlign(HAlign_Fill)
            .VAlign(VAlign_Fill) [
                SNew(SImage)
                    .ColorAndOpacity(FColor::Black)
            ]
            + SOverlay::Slot()
            .HAlign(HAlign_Fill)
            .VAlign(VAlign_Fill)
            .Padding(ContentPadding) [
                SNew(SVerticalBox)
                    +SVerticalBox::Slot() [
                        SNew(STextBlock)
                            .Text(TitleText)
                    ]
            ]
    ];
}

#undef LOCTEXT_NAMESPACE
```

Comment: Error message tells you that you are not providing the appropriate number of arguments to the function in question – either you need none at all or more than one. I do not see where you actually call that function so it seems as if it is hidden in one of the macros that are around there everywhere. As not familiar with unreal all I can tell you is to look at that exact line in the header and check which arguments are passed to – maybe `__VA_ARGS__` and thus a variadic macro is involved, so check if you provide sufficient arguments to these macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to declare **Construct** function with an upper case **'C'**.

*Credit: splodginald*